# Report Designer V2.0 Custom Code Unable to pass a parameter as type Date

Tags: vb.net, tfs, vbscript, report, reporting-services

I am attempting to create a report using report designer V2.0 and have written a VB function to calculate the number of weekdays between two dates.

I have written the code in vb.Net and ported it into the custom code tab within in the report.

The signature of the function looks like this

```
    Public Function CalculateWorkdays(ByVal startdate As Date, ByVal enddate As Date) As String
        Return "Test"
    End Function
```

I then attempt to pass my report variables to this function

```
    =Code.CalculateWorkdays(CDate(Parameter.MyStartDate), CDate(Parameter.MyEndDate))
```

This fails to execute

If I change the signature to

```
      Public Function CalculateWorkdays(ByVal startdate As String, ByVal enddate As String) As String
             Return "Test"
      End Function

      =Code.CalculateWorkdays(Parameter.MyStartDate, Parameter.MyEndDate)
```

This executes and succeeds.

So rather than try and cast/convert my string dates prior to the function call I've tried to do it within the function itself e.g.

```
     Dim startdate as Date
     startdate = Date.Parse(strstartdate)
```

but any attempt to cast/convert the string to a Date type within the function fails.  The strange thing is I can do things like

```
    Public Function CalculateWorkDays(ByVal strstartdate As String) As String
       Dim startDate as Date
       startDate = Today.AddDays(30)
       Return startDate.ToString()
    End Function
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this problem by reformatting the date string that I was passing to something which the Date type could understand.

My query was passing the dates in the following format 30/01/2012 (dd/mm/yyyy)

Reformatting the date string to (mm/dd/yyyy) meant that I could now do

```
 Dim mydate as Date   
 mydate = Date.Parse(strmydate)
```

I'm still not sure why the date needed to be formatted as such but think it is to do with the CultureInfo default.

Hope this helps someone.